# To calculate age from dob and current date in java

Tags: java, mysql

I am using following method to calculate age from dob and current date in java,dob is stored in database table,using getter setter methods dob value is derived and passing dob to getAge1 method,in method query runs fine in php myadmin mysql console,when i am storing query's result in resultset its giving null value here in int age variable.

```
public int getAge1(int id,String dob)
{


    try { 
        System.out.println("DOB is:"+dob);
        System.out.println("Id is:"+id);
         Connection conn = null;
         conn = DbConnection.getConnection();
         PreparedStatement ps = null;
         ResultSet rs = null;   

         String s3 = "SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,"+ dob +",CURDATE()) from custregister where cid="+ id ;

         System.out.println("sql :"+s3);
            ps = conn.prepareStatement(s3);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) 
            {

                int s2 =rs.getInt(1);
                System.out.println("Age is "+s2);
                age=s2;
            }
    }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}   
    //SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, 'dob', CURDATE()) AS age;
    return age;
}
```

Comment: just execute the statement...and if you use preparedstatement pass paratmeter `id` after that

Comment: tried using statement executeQuery() instead of preparedStatement still getting int null value 0 as result

Comment: I am not getting any error,the value is not fetching form either resultset or from query

Comment: Yes query is giving proper result when executed as SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, dob,CURDATE()) from custregister where cid=101 ;

Comment: Would it not be easier/better to simply select the value from the database and calculate it at the application level? This allows for more flexibility (e.g. you need the date for something else, need to take into consideration locales,...)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
     SELECT 
     TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, dob, CURDATE())AS AGE 
     from custregister 
     where cid= your id ;
```

***http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff***

**update:1**

```
String s3 = "SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,"+ dob +",CURDATE()) from custregister  where cid='+id'" ;
```

Comment: yes my query is running fine but not getting resulset value properly

Answer (score 0):

Add single Quotation marks around the date value being passed into that SELECT statement.

Comment: (a) Your comments are unintelligible. (B) Compare the value of your `s3` SELECT statement string with the examples in the doc linked in the answer by jmail. Notice the quote marks.